# Class 'App\Providers\TeamWorkServiceProvider' not found -- on AWS Server

Tags: php, laravel, backend, service-provider

This provider is completely working fine on the local machine. This issue occurs only on the server.
I had created a Custom Teamwork service provider Also register on app/config as below  -
App\Providers\TeamWorkServiceProvider::class,
Also Created separate directory under app folder :app/Teamwork
Below image  he code of TeamworkServiceProvider.php file which is inside the provider folder: [Folder snaps with teamworkServicePRovider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7zkH.png)

[This is an issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcht6.png)

To resolve this issue I had already tried below points:

1. delete vendor and run composer install
2. also run php artisan config:cache
3. remove bootstrap/config/cache file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class is not called `TeamWorkServiceProvider` it is `TeamworkServiceProvider`, the case matters because of how composer will match up the class name to a filename. On a case sensitive filesystem `TeamWorkServiceProvider.php` and `TeamworkServiceProvider.php` are different files.

Comment: Thank you so much @lagbox..  your suggestion work . This issue has been resolved. once again thanks a lot